# Why the crontab run in duplicated times?

Tags: cron

I have added an crontab like this:

```
*/15 * * * * /home/test/demo.py
```

However, it runs in two times. And, we can see that two logs are logged in /var/log/cron:

> Jun 30 20:00:01 demo1.ops.dev CROND[29181]: (root) CMD (/home/test/a.py)
>
> Jun 30 20:00:01 demo1.ops.dev CROND[29180]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
>
> Jun 30 20:00:01 demo1.ops.dev CROND[29189]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
>
> Jun 30 20:00:01 demo1.ops.dev CROND[29190]: (root) CMD (/home/test/a.py)

Answer (score 0):

Answered by myself,

- I restart the crond daemon. It can not resolve the problem,
- I restart the machine. It can not be scheduled properly.